# How to change font awesome icon with click event?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I have specified font awesome in a XAML file. The problem is that how to change font awesome icon when clicked the button, and change it back to original when clicked the button again.

**FontAwesome in Xamarin Forms**

```xml
    <ImageButton x:Name="stopWatch" BackgroundColor="Green" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60"                   
                         VerticalOptions ="End" HorizontalOptions ="Center" Margin="10,25,10,10"
                         CornerRadius="30"
                         Padding="1" Opacity="0.5"
                             Clicked="Button_OnPressed" >
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{x:StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}" 
                             Glyph="{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowAltCircleDown}"
                             Color="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Green,
                                                     Light=White}"/>
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                    <ImageButton.IsVisible>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
                            <On Platform="iOS"
                    Value="true" />
                            <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="false" />
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </ImageButton.IsVisible>
                </ImageButton>
```

Clicked Event without font awesome (I cannot specify the icon with font awesome)

```
    private void Button_OnPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (ButtonBackColor == true)
                    stopWatch.Source = "connection.png";
                else stopWatch.Source = "signal.png";
                ButtonBackColor = !ButtonBackColor;
            }
```

**Update**

**Defined fontAwesome in App.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP"
                    Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
            </OnPlatform>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
                <On Platform="UWP"
                    Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                        x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
                <On Platform="Android"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS"
                    Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP"
                    Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
            </OnPlatform>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Did you try to use  `stopWatch.Source = new FontImageSource() { FontFamily=xx ,Glyph =xx };` to set the awesome icon.

Comment: the syntax is correct, there are no errors after compilation. However, the icon cannot be shown.

Comment: It may be the size of icon, when I click the button, the icon is disappeared,

Comment: It may be incorrect; I copied a full text to the property "Source",  var SourceGreen = new FontImageSource()
            {
                FontFamily = "{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowAltCircleDown}",
                Glyph = "{x:StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}",
               
            };

Comment: you have swapped values of  FontFamily  and Glyph

Comment: typo in this comment. Correct in the source var SourceBlue = new FontImageSource()
            {
                FontFamily = "{x:StaticResource FontAwesomeRegular}",
                Glyph = "{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowAltCircleDown}",
                Color = Color.Blue
            };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `AppThemeBinding` it seems not to be supported from the code till now [Ability to set AppThemeBinding on Styles in code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11341), you can test `Application.Current.UserAppTheme` one time but it won't be dynamic.

```
using System.Linq;
...

private void Button_OnPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("FontAwesomeRegular", out object fontFamily);

   if (fontFamily == null)
      //this should not occurred, throw an exception

    string fontFamilyString = Device.RuntimePlatform switch
            {
                Device.Android => (fontFamily as OnPlatform<string>).Platforms.Where(x => x.Platform[0].Equals(Device.Android)).Select(x => (string)x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                Device.iOS => (fontFamily as OnPlatform<string>).Platforms.Where(x => x.Platform[0].Equals(Device.iOS)).Select(x => (string)x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                Device.UWP => (fontFamily as OnPlatform<string>).Platforms.Where(x => x.Platform[0].Equals(Device.UWP)).Select(x => (string)x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                _ => string.Empty
            };

 if (ButtonBackColor == true)
 {
     stopWatch.Source = new FontImageSource()
     { 
       FontFamily= fontFamilyString,
       Glyph = FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowAltCircleDown,
       Color = Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark
               ? Color.Green
               : Color.White;
     };
 }
 else
 {
     stopWatch.Source = new FontImageSource()
     { 
       FontFamily= fontFamilyString,
       Glyph = FontAwesomeIcons.ArrowAltCircleUp,
       Color = Application.Current.UserAppTheme == OSAppTheme.Dark
               ? Color.Green
               : Color.White;
     };
 }

 ButtonBackColor = !ButtonBackColor;
}
```

Comment: I defined various fonts in App.xaml. How to assign "FontFamily" in "Button_OnPressed"?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. " UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"; I try to figure out what's going on

Comment: I try to replace FontAwesomeRegular with FontAwesomeRegular2, if the resource doesn't exit. It can't be shown and exception hasn't been raised. The exception is happening  in the main.cs :  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
            // you can specify it here.
            UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
        }

Comment: I don't know why `(fontFamily as OnPlatform<string>).Android` or .iOS is null that why I got to use Linq

Comment: Thanks for your help, try to apply your comment, get back to you shortly.

Comment: string fontFamilyString has never been updated.  I try to fix it with this statement "FontFamily = (OnPlatform<string>)Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeRegular"],", it seems it works.